# Python - Problem with checking if element is in list

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, if-statement

I came across a problem in Python and since I do this for fun and not as a professional I don't get why this does not work. I have a list that contains other lists with two numbers in each one. This function should check wether the element +1 and the element -1 are elements of my tp list. If yes, append them to stack. Code:

```
def check():
    tp = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
    stack = []
    for i in tp:
        a = i[0]
        b = i[1]
        if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp:
            stack.append(i)
    return stack
```

Unfortunately the output is:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

`[1, 2]` is correct because `[0, 1]` and `[2, 3]` are elements of `tp`.

`[2, 2]` is correct because `[1, 1]` and `[3, 3]` are elements of `tp`.

Why does this function give me the other two also?
For instance: first element of tp is [0,1] -> [-1,0] and [1,2] should be the calculated outputs but obviously [-1,0] is not in this list. Where is my (probably obvious) mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] in tp and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp:`

Comment: because you evalute `True` in your first checker `if [(a - 1), (b - 1)]`  = list is not empty wich is `True`, you have to check your first checker in `tp` so the `True` evaluation gets`True` for the elements..

Answer (score 1):

`if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp`
Should be `if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] in tp and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp`

`[(a - 1), (b - 1)]` by itself is a non-empty list, which is considered truthy, making your if `if True and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp`

Answer (score 0):

`and` doesn't distribute over `in`. Your condition is being parsed as

```
if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] and ([(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp):
```

Since `[(a - 1), (b - 1)]` is truthy, the condition always succeeds.

You need to use `in` for each list you want to check:

```
if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] in tp and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp:
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are checking two things:

1: `[(a - 1), (b - 1)]` is not empty (which is always `True` in your example)

2: `[(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp`

What you want to check is: `([(a - 1), (b - 1)] in tp) and ([(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp)`

```
def check():
    tp = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
    stack = []
    for i in tp:
        a = i[0]
        b = i[1]
        if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] in tp and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp:
            stack.append(i)
    return stack
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement you have is not correct.

It should be:

```
if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] in tp and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp:
```

instead of:

```
if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp:
```

With `if [(a - 1), (b - 1)] and [(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp`, the condition is evaluated to `True` if:

1. `[(a - 1), (b - 1)]` satisfies meaning the list is not empty
2. `[(a + 1), (b + 1)] in tp` satisfies

Since condition `1` is always `True`, it boils down to the second condition which is also satisfied for `[0, 1]` and `[1, 1]` so you get that in the result as well.